# structuring types for blocks of different types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to design a CMS-like block system where the input is some JSON:

```json
[{
  type: "title",
  text: "hello"
}, {
  type: "description",
  text: "world"
}, {
  type: "button",
  text: "Click Me",
  href: "/"
}]
```

And I'd define the "Block" type system like this:

```js
namespace Blocks {
  interface Title {
     type: "title";
     text: string;
  }
  interface Description {
     type: "description";
     text: string;
  }  
  interface Button {
     type: "button";
     text: string;
     href: string;
     color?: string;
  }
}
```

How would I structure this so that I can pass a generic "block" type, which would type-check according to the `type`? Or is this the wrong way to structure this?

```
interface Page {
   blocks: Block[]
}

interface Block extends AnyOfThoseBlocks { // how would I extend all types of the namespace?
   blocks?: Block[]; // blocks can contain nested other blocks
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you want to parse the JSON directly into plain objects that will conform to these interfaces, in lieu of having concrete classes that would have to be loaded off of the plain objects.

Structurally, your `Title`, `Description`, etc., interfaces need to each extend the `Block` interface, not the other way around. That way they will inherit the `blocks` property. So, perhaps:

```
interface Block {
    type: string;
    blocks: Block[];
}
namespace Blocks {
    export interface Title extends Block { type: 'title'; /* ... */ }
    export interface Description extends Block { type: 'description'; /* ... */ }
    export interface Button extends Block { type: 'button'; /* ... */ }
}
```

If you then have an object of type `Block` somewhere, you can check its `type` field and cast it to the appropriate interface based on that:

```
function logHref(block: Block): void {
    if (block.type === 'button') {
        console.log((block as Blocks.Button).href);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you aren't achieving real type safety this way, as your JSON could somehow have a malformed object like `{"type":"button","text":"Hello World"}` (missing `href`). You could use [ajv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv) or a similar tool for proper safety.